# Lock page content aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

How to lock aspect ratio of my page like in example?
Responsive for 16:9 (for example responsive for 1920x1080 and 2560x1440), but displays 16:9 when user's display is 21:9 or 32:9.
I tried media queries and aspect-ratio but it doesn't work like I want.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vpsdr.png)

Comment: Alternatively, you can try `max-width`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I did it the easiest possible way, changing max-width to max-height in media queries like

```
const Content = styled.div`
    width: 98%;
    height: 100%;
    @media (max-height: 1080px) {
        max-width: 1920px;
    }
    @media (min-height: 1081px) and (max-height: 1440px) {
        max-width: 2560px;
    }
    @media (min-height: 1441px) and (max-height: 2160px) {
        max-width: 3840px;
    }
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.lock{
  max-height:400px;width:90%;margin:auto;border:1px solid #ddd;overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" class="">
<Button id="btnLock" onclick="GetLock()">Get Lock</Button>
<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Edit the code in the window to the left, and click "Run" to view the result.</p>
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">
   <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Edit the code in the window to the left, and click "Run" to view the result.</p>
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">

  <h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Edit the code in the window to the left, and click "Run" to view the result.</p>
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">

<h1>This is a Heading</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>Edit the code in the window to the left, and click "Run" to view the result.</p>
<img src="avatar.png" alt="Avatar" style="width:200px">


</div>
<script>
var lock=false;
function GetLock()
{
   if(lock)
   {
      var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
      element.classList.remove("lock");
      lock=false;
   }
   else
   {
      var element = document.getElementById("wrapper");
      element.classList.add("lock");
      lock=true;
   }
}
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: yeah but, it's not responsive for higher resolutions like 4k, I think I should use max-width with media queries